# restricted ssh tunnel through external facing server to mysql on internal server

Tags: ssh, mysql, ssh-tunneling

Using my user I'm able to set up an ssh tunnel to mysql (port 3306) on an internal server by tunneling through an external server using:

```
ssh -L 33306:localhost:33306 me@external.com ssh -L 33306:localhost:3306 me@internal
```

I'm then able to log into mysql with:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33306 -u me -p my_database
```

Now, I'd like to set up another user to be able to do the same but not be able to do anything else (not login, access other ports, etc).

In their authorized_keys on external.com I have:

```
permitopen="internal:3306",permitopen="localhost:33306",no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA...==
```

I don't have any restrictions in their authorized_keys on internal (not sure if I need them - will explore once I get this working).

Then, when I do:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33306 -u me -p my_database
```

It seems to work in that it asks for my password. I enter the password, but then mysql gives me:

```
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

and in the terminal where I set up the tunnel I get:

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

When it asks for the mysql password is that just happening locally before it tries to communicate with the server? Are my permitopen flags wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The problem is that I had set that user to not have a shell on both machines so that they could only use the first server as a tunnel.

The above command actually does work.